# iOS create ad-hoc network

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, jailbreak

Is it possible (with or without jailbreak) to create a wireless access point from iOS 12 to serve as a 'router'? 
I don't want to share iOS internet connection, the phone will be located in a place where there is no data connection, and Personal Hotspot feature on iOS only is available when mobile data is ON, I'm just using it to act as a router between two android devices: First device will be streaming video through http (with [IP webcam app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=es)) and second device will display it in a web browser.

So for this I need to have a DHCP server on iOS which assigns addresses to the devices, a discoverable service, and a router service which routes packages. I'm guessing there is already an app/tweak which covers all of this but been searching for a while and all I could find was about using iOS Personal Hotspot feature, or outdated Tethering apps on Cydia. 
Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a specific reason you don‘t set up the network directly with the android devices?

Comment: That would be great, although I don't know exactly how to do it. 
Streaming device is an old  < 4.x android version, which as I car read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p doesn't allow p2p connection.This device is using IP webcam which starts an streaming server with http so it needs an assigned ip address